# vue 3 composition api route query is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

this is my **search.vue** component:

```
 setup() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const route = useRoute();
    const searchQuery = ref("");

    const search = debounce((query) => {
      router.push({
        name: "Home",
        query: {
          ...route.query,
          search: query,
        },
      });
    }, 1000);

    watch(
      () => searchQuery.value,
      (value) => search(value)
    );

    nextTick(() => {
      console.log(route.query);
    });

    if (route.query.search) {
      searchQuery.value = route.query.search;
    }

    return {
      searchQuery,
    };
  },
```

The problem is that `route.query` object is always empty. but I can access `route.query` in other components easily with no problem.

this is my URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/?search=apple
```

Comment: you overwrite it with the other query variable every time. Given the assumption it only contains the `search` key.

Comment: What's the purpose of searchQuery? There's route.query already. You can react to changes with onBeforeRouteUpdate.

Comment: @EstusFlask I have a search input, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't access the query param in the layouts component.